# Problema para insertar una línea en fputcsv

Tags: php

Tengo una clase *totales()* que genera un registro que contiene importes por mes (en el ejemplo 4 meses)

```
Array
(
    [01] => 9040.70
    [02] => 3077.50
    [03] => 3232.50
    [04] => 2300.00
)
```

En el código ya puse la cabecera.

```
fputcsv($archivo, array('CODIGO', 'NOMBRE', 'ENE', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'ABR');
$totales = $ctacte->totales($anio);
fputcsv($archivo, array('', 'TOTALES S/.', $totales));
```

Pero muestra el siguiente mensaje:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in \localhost\desarrollo\reporte.php on line 96
```

Esta es la línea:

```
fputcsv($archivo, array('', 'TOTALES S/.', $totales));
```

Esto es lo que quiero conseguir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El aviso (*Notice*) te señala que un arreglo se está intentado convertir a cadena.
Evidentemente la variable `$totales` es un arreglo y se espera que sea una cadena.

### Solución:

Suponiendo que la variable `$totales` es un arreglo como el siguiente:

```
$totales = array(
  '01' => 9040.70
  '02' => 3077.50
  '03' => 3232.50
  '04' => 2300.00
);
```

Podrías utilizar [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) junto con [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values) así:

```
fputcsv($archivo, array_merge(array('', 'TOTALES S/.'), array_values($totales)));
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/a68f4)</kbd>

Comment: Esa combinación no la conocía.